# Gulp not compiling sass although not showing any errors

Tags: gulp, gulp-sass

**SOLUTION:**

Renaming _styles.scss to test.scss and _styles.css to test.css fixed it. Why?

---

It was working fine earlier. Now nothing is being compiled.The css files are not being created and are empty or not updated.

terminal:

```
asd@dsa:/var/www/html/mg/app/design/frontend/Training/default$ sudo gulp default
[sudo] password for asd: 
[14:50:48] Using gulpfile /var/www/html/mg/app/design/frontend/Training/default/gulpfile.js
[14:50:48] Starting 'default'...
[14:50:48] Finished 'default' after 14 ms
^C
asd@dsa:/var/www/html/mg/app/design/frontend/Training/default$ sudo gulp styles 
[14:50:56] Using gulpfile /var/www/html/mg/app/design/frontend/Training/default/gulpfile.js
[14:50:56] Starting 'styles'...
[14:50:56] Finished 'styles' after 13 ms
asd@dsa:/var/www/html/mg/app/design/frontend/Training/default$ sudo gulp pub
[14:51:02] Using gulpfile /var/www/html/mg/app/design/frontend/Training/default/gulpfile.js
[14:51:02] Starting 'pub'...
[14:51:02] Finished 'pub' after 12 ms
```

gulpfile.js:

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');

gulp.task('styles', function() {
    gulp.src('web/sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('web/css/'));
});

gulp.task('pub', function() {
    gulp.src('web/sass/**/*.scss')
        .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('../../../../../pub/static/frontend/Scandi/default/en_US/css/'));
});

gulp.task('default', function() {
    gulp.watch('web/sass/**/*.scss',['styles']);
});
```

[image]

Comment: I think it should be `.pipe( sass() ).on('error', sass.logError)` instead of `.pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))`

Comment: @Sergeon didn't change anything.

Comment: The main sass file should not have an underscore in its name. `_styles.scss` should be `styles.scss` - because it is not a partial.

Comment: @jacmoe thanks, you can post it as answer.

Comment: Alright - will do :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gulp-sass will happily compile everything that is not a Sass partial automatically whenever it changes.

By default, every Sass file that is prefixed with an underscore is a [partial](http://sass-lang.com/documentation/file.SASS_REFERENCE.html#partials), and meant to be imported into one or more Sass 'master' files.

In practice, this means that you need at least one Sass file not prepended with an underscore for compilation to work/output properly.

In your case, simply rename `_styles.scss` to `styles.scss` and that should result in a `styles.css` in your target CSS directory. :)

Partials allows you to organize your Sass source code in very neat ways, see [The Sass Way - How to structure a Sass project](http://thesassway.com/beginner/how-to-structure-a-sass-project)